# Create Sparkling Water Cloud in Databricks using Python Notebook

Tags: pyspark, h2o, databricks, sparkling-water

I am trying to launch a Sparkling Water cloud within Spark using Databricks. I've attached the H2O library (3.16.0.2), PySparkling (pysparkling 0.4.6), and the Sparkling Water jar (sparkling-water-assembly_2.11-2.1.10-all.jar) to the cluster I'm running (Spark 2.1, Auto-updating Scala 1.1.1).

I succesfully import the required libraries below:

```
from pysparkling import *
import h2o
```

Yet when I try to initialize the Sparkling Water cloud using the following commands:

`hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate(spark)`

or

`H2OContext.getOrCreate(sc)`

I get the same error:

`NameError: name 'H2OContext' is not defined`

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4043510449425708> in <module>()
----> 1 H2OContext.getOrCreate(sc)

NameError: name 'H2OContext' is not defined
```

For what it's worth I can initialize the Sparkling Water cloud using this [Scala documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/h2o-sparkling-water.html):

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.h2o._
val h2oConf = new H2OConf(sc).set("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
val h2oContext = H2OContext.getOrCreate(sc, h2oConf)

import org.apache.spark.h2o._
h2oConf: org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OConf =
Sparkling Water configuration:
  backend cluster mode : internal
  workers              : None
  cloudName            : sparkling-water-root_app-20171222131625-0000
  flatfile             : true
  clientBasePort       : 54321
  nodeBasePort         : 54321
  cloudTimeout         : 60000
  h2oNodeLog           : INFO
  h2oClientLog         : WARN
  nthreads             : -1
  drddMulFactor        : 10
h2oContext: org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext =

Sparkling Water Context:
 * H2O name: sparkling-water-root_app-20171222131625-0000
 * cluster size: 1
 * list of used nodes:
  (executorId, host, port)
  ------------------------
  (x,xx.xxx.xxx.x,54321)
  ------------------------

  Open H2O Flow in browser: http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:54321 (CMD + click in Mac OSX)
```

but this pipeline may not always use Databricks so it needs to be all in PySpark and Databricks doesn't have a corresponding PySpark example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pysparkling, you need to first create a PyPi library for `h2o_pysparkling_2.1` since you are using a Spark 2.1 cluster. The library you attached, `pysparkling` is something different. Also, you do not need to attach all those other libraries as the `h2o_pysparkling_2.1` package will already import the other necessary libraries.

Once you do that you can run:

```
from pysparkling import *

h2oConf = H2OConf(spark)
h2oConf.set("spark.ui.enabled", False)

h2oContext = H2OContext.getOrCreate(spark, h2oConf)
```

Comment: I get:  

from pysparkling import *
[WARNING] H2O requires colorama module of version 0.3.8 or newer. You have version 0.3.7.
You can upgrade to the newest version of the module running from the command line
    $ pip2 install --upgrade colorama

h2oContext = H2OContext.getOrCreate(spark)

py4j.Py4JException: Method getOrCreate([class org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession, class org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OConf]) does not exist
...

Comment: I updated the code example. Please first detach all previous libraries, restart the cluster to flush out the dependencies, attach the h2o_pysparkling_2.1, run the code above. I just verified this myself on a Spark 2.1 cluster.